Are you not supposed to sum booleans in Pandas dataframes?
I am trying to count the number of t tests that produce significant results in each column of a potentially large dataframe full of t statistics.
Both of the answers I have seen (a b) suggest that the correct way to sum columns of Boolean variables in a dataframe is like this:
summed_df = df.sum(axis=1)

However, when I do this in PyCharm it comes up with an Amber warning "Unresolved attribute reference 'sum' for class 'bool'". Yet the code still works as expected. So I'm wondering if the above method is out of date or I'm missing something. My full code is shown below (thickt is a function that returns many t statistics in a dataframe):
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import t
from Main import thickt

thicknesses = [2, 2.5, 3, 3.2, 3.5, 4, 5, 20]
tranche_size = 10_000
sample_size = 20
pval = 0.05
t2crit = t.ppf(pval/2, sample_size-1)**2
print(t2crit)
tstats = []

for a in thicknesses:
tstats.append(thickt(tranche_size, sample_size, a))

data = pd.DataFrame(tstats, thicknesses)
print(data)
tests = data > t2crit
print(tests)
count = tests.sum(axis=1)
print(count)


What is print (data.head().to_dict()) ?

@jezrael it looks like {0: {2.0: 1.4569784128940708, 2.5: 5.042473366523591, 3.0: 2.342549012438915, 3.2: 1.6998336075610612, 3.5: 0.04449310472705845}, 1: {2.0: 4.740078489157436, 2.5: 6.090072267339777, 3.0: 2.2492344624391376, 3.2: 2.7217454013495175, 3.5: 0.44769187488274087}, 2: {2.0: 1.315391645204874, 2.5: 1.8978485575099708, 3.0: 4.234094892346138, 3.2: 0.6701290028510889, 3.5: 1.2107070426924773}, etc.

Hmmm, tested and for me working perfectly. Only one idea, how working count = tests.astype(int).sum(axis=1) ?

@jezrael is that not the expected result?

For me your solution working well, but idea is casting to integer, output should be same.

@jezrael that code gives the same, correct, result but it also has an amber warning: "Unresolved attribute reference 'astype' for class 'bool'"

Hmmm, I dont use PyCharm, so no idea.

This question is similar to: Check for pandas duplicates in a PEP8 way. I believe the tests = data > t2crit is what is throwing pycharm off. It's assuming that output will be a boolean, so that when you do test.sum() it's worried that sum() is not a valid method of test which it incorrectly believes to be a boolean. You are doing things correctly, pycharm is just making a bad guess.

@JNevill thank you, that does look like the same issue I've been having, and it's comforting to know I'm not doing anything wrong.
